# Creating a PDF file from a folder structure containing images

Tags: python, windows, pdf-generation

I am looking for a way to generate a PDF from a Folder with several pictures.

I have many pictures like this:

```
folder1/
Image1.jpg
Image2.jpg 
......

folder2/
img1.jpg
pict.jpg
name1.jpg
```

I am looking for a way where we can automatically generate a PDF using the name of the pictures saved, and if possible, load pictures in to the PDF automatically.

My code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

# Define the path to the folder containing the images
path = "path/to/folder"

# Create a new PDF file
output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()

# Loop through each image in the folder and add it to the PDF file
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
        # Open the image file using the Pillow library
        with Image.open(os.path.join(path, filename)) as img:
            # Create a new page in the PDF file
            pdf_page = output_pdf.addBlankPage(width=img.width, height=img.height)
            # Convert the image to RGB mode and add it to the PDF page
            img_rgb = img.convert('RGB')
            pdf_page.mergeRGBImage(img_rgb)
            
            # Add the file name to the PDF page
            c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_page)
            c.setFont("Helvetica", 8)
            c.drawString(10, 10, filename)
            c.save()

# Save the output PDF file
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as out_file:
    output_pdf.write(out_file)
```

Comment: You can do that with Python, would that be ok as well?

Comment: yeah,,that fine too,Any idea how can we do that,

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommendation, i would use PIL to achieve what you want:

```
from PIL import Image  # install by > python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow  # ref. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#basic-installation

images = [
    Image.open("C:/Users/test/Desktop/testpics/" + f)
    for f in ["pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg"]
]

pdf_path = "C:/Users/test/Desktop/pics123.pdf"
    
images[0].save(
    pdf_path, "PDF" ,resolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:]
)
```

Of course you have to edit your current path of the images.
In the for loop you have to specify which images you wanna saves as a pdf, as you mentioned you wanna specify which pictures should be saved.

If you are running the script all the mentioned pictures will be saved as a pdf in the mentioned path.

If you have any additional questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: for filename in os.listdir(path):
 if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
      
        with Image.open(os.path.join(path, filename)) as img:
           
            pdf_page = output_pdf.addBlankPage(width=img.width, height=img.height)
            
         
            pdf_page.drawImage(os.path.join(path, filename), x=0, y=0, width=img.width, height=img.height)
            
          
            c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_page)
            c.setFont("Helvetica", 8)
            c.drawString(10, 10, filename)
            c.save()

Comment: What is this answer about? Python Example?  Have you tried my code?